Laravel livewire need to remove debounce on inputs
I have a livewire form that receives inputs from a scanner.  The scanner inputs the scanned serial number and sends a carriage return at the end, emulating a Return key being sent from the keyboard:
<input wire:keydown.enter="add" wire:model.live.debounce.0ms="serial_number" type="text" ... \>
On Enter keydown, the 'add' function is fired, adding the serial number to an array.  However, the user reports a very slow response, which I assumed was the default debounce of 150ms.
Since these are scanned rapidly - each press of the trigger enters the serial number + Enter key essentially instantly - any debounce is slowing the process to a crawl, forcing them to wait between trigger presses on the scanner.
I tried setting the debounce to 0ms as above, but this does not seem to allow the save function to be called instantly as needed.
I refactored a form that previously used vanilla javascript to receive scanned inputs calling a function that saved the serial number in the input to an array on Enter keydown . This worked fine as there was no delay between adds, but since replacing with livewire, the response time essentially renders the form unusable.

Have you tried using lazy? 
